# Apostrophe s' or s's - When to use each?

Tags: apostrophe

In this sentence should I use Apostrophe as s's or s'? I am always confused with what exactly the rule behind s' and s's. The sentence is:

> Hours later Fadnavis's resignation, the the NCP-Congress leaders combined met Governor and staked claim to form the Government.

Fadnavis is the name of the Chief Minister (for your understanding)

Comment: what is the correct form: Fudnavis's or Fadnavis'

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in the
singular or *“**these** Xes”* in the plural in many common and less
exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners don’t realize
that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this, that, these,
those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the use of so-called 'zero genitive', marked by a simple apostrophe in spelling ('), as opposed to the *'s* genitive, Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech and Svartvik specify in *A Comprehensive grammar of the English Language* (pp. 320 & 321) that:

> In addition to its normal use with regular plurals such as *boys'*, the 'zero genitive' is used to avoid repetitive or awkward combinations of sounds in the following cases:
>
> (i) with Greek names of more than one syllable that end in *-s*, as in:
>
> *Euripides'* /di:z/ plays, *Xerxes'* army, *Socrates'* wife
>
> (ii) with many other names ending in /z/, where in speech zero is a variant of the regular /ɪz/ genitive.  There is vacillation both in the pronunciation and in the spelling of these names, but most commonly the pronunciation is /ɪz/, and the spelling is an apostrophe only.  (In the following examples, the minority form is given in parentheses.)
>
> WRITTEN FORMS
>
> *Burns'* (*Burns's*) poem
>
> *Dickens'* (*Dickens's*) novels
>
> *Jones'* (*Jones's*) car
>
> SPOKEN FORMS
>
> /ˈbɜ:nzɪz (bɜ:nz)/
>
> /ˈdɪkɪnzɪz (ˈdɪkɪnz)/
>
> /ˈdʒəunzɪz (dʒəunz)/
>
> Names ending in other sibilants than /z/ have the regular /ɪz/ genitive: *Ross's* /ˈrɒsɪz/ *theories*.  However, *Jesus* and *Moses*  normally have the zero form of the spoken genitive, /ˈdʒi:zəs/ and /ˈməuzɪz/, and are written *Jesus'* and *Moses'* (as well as *Jesus's* and *Moses's*).
>
> (iii) with fixed expression of the form *for* . . . *sake*, as in *for goddness' sake*, *for conscience' sake*, where the noun ends in /s/.

*Fadnavis* presumably does not end with a /z/ sound but with /s/, just like *Ross* in Quirk's example, and therefore should form its genitive with *'s*, giving *Fadnavis's*.